# How to append function to a list then print it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a basic recipe viewer in python, I stumbled across a problem of which when I try to print my saved recipe it displays `[None]`, as seen the recipe is firstly a function, then it is appended onto a list then I try to print it when loading it.

The code below can explain more. How do I stop the `[None, None]` from appearing? The code below is a sample I made which I could easily adapt to resolving my issue in my recipe rather than posting my entire code on here.

```
b = [] #this is meant to resemble my list

def function():  # this is meant to resemble my recipe
     print("hi")


function()
a = input('write 1 = ') # this is meant to resemble the user to saving the recipe

if a == '1':
    b.append(function()) # this is meant to resemble me saving the recipe onto a list


print(b) # this is meant to resemble me loading the recipe
```

When I run my code , sorry don't have enough reputation points to post an image but this is what comes up in the python shell

```
hi
write '1' = 1 #user input
hi
[None]
```

Comment: Cannot test but I think you meant the function to return the string "hi", and not print it. Like this, you first call the function (so you print "hi") then you print the return value of your function which is None indeed. Try replacing "print("hi")" with "return "hi" and see if that's what you were expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your function. You are **printing**, but that's not the same thing.

Use `return` to return the value:

```
def function():
     return "hi"
```

`print()` writes to your terminal, the caller of the function is not given that output.

You can always use `print()` to print the return value:

```
print(function())
```